# Download certain part of HTML code

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make a push notification about Internet page update, but downloading the full page (700k) again every minute is quite troublesome for users. Is there is a way to download only a specific part of page?

As far as I have read there isn't any way to get delta information about the page. Is there a method which allows that? I haven't found one for a day (if there is, how can I locate the certain byte where my information is placed in the first place?

Comment: Is this your page? Why is it 700KB?

Comment: "Why worry about server-side databases? Just send **all of the data** with each HTTP request and let the JavaScript sort it out client-side!"

Comment: We need more info.  Downloading a specific part of HTML can be achieved with Asynchronous Javascript And XML, i.e. AJAX.

Comment: Not mine. Heavy table with data.

Comment: Well i am unfamiliar with java scripts only Objective-c(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a Range header like this:

```
Range: bytes=0-1000
```

This will obviously get you the first 1000 bytes.

Comment: This is really crude and not a standard practise.

Comment: @DanKanze Well, I agree to a certain point, but I think is usable in some cases. If he needs like 100 bytes from 700KB page, isn't it better for users and server to just fetch those 100 bytes?

Comment: No because you are just getting the first 100 bytes. What if he needed the 100 bytes in the middle? What if the content is dynamic?

Comment: It's not just first 100 bytes, you can declare from byte position as well as end byte position, that's why it'c called range. 
If the content is dynamic he most likely can't use this method, but I'm guessing it's not dynamic otherwise he wouldn't ask for such a solution.

Comment: lol there are so many other factors. like what if browsers set different headers. or what if doctype is forced in different browsers? cache issues cross browser? all fo these factors can affect byte postion for start AND end. this just wont work. ever. period.

Comment: Headers don't have anything to do with byte position of content. Plus he never mentioned any browser, for all I know he is building Windows/Linux/Mac application.

Comment: Headers do have ALOT to do with byte position content. find me ONE source that says they do not.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is learn some basics in AJAX calls.

You set an auto timer to reload div contents on whatever needs to be updated.

Comment: Well, it's time to learn about it though surfing for an hour didn't do any good last time. Maybe you could call me method ?